# CSS problem in Drupal website in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Ok, here is the deal. The following code is stated in my Drupal page.tpl.php and yet IE6 doesn't want to accept the `display:none` part.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .coda-nav{display:none; position:absolute; width:400px;height:20px;top:260px;right:100px;z-index:125421;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Clearing the Drupal cache or the browser cache didn't help.
What is wrong with my code (it seems ok to me?)

And don't ask why I still write code for IE6, it's already humiliating enough :)

Comment: Are you sure your markup has class `coda-nav` and that the `display` setting isn't overridden by another rule somewhere else?

Comment: Since (for some reason) there is no other css file declared for IE6, I assume, this is the only line of code applying for IE6.

Comment: No. *All* CSS is used by IE 6, the extra rule you mention is *only* applied to IE 6, but not to other browsers.

Comment: doesn't this line override the others? Should it make a difference when you add `!important`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All CSS rules are applied according to the [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade), whether they live inside an IE-specific conditional comment or not.

In this case, adding `!important` to the value may solve your problem, unless other values that also are `!important` are specified with higher precedence.

---

BTW, if you only want to address IE 6 and 7, you can also add an other word than `important` after `!`, like

```
display: none !hotdog;
```

In those broswers, this will have the same effect as adding `!important`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hotdog? LOL :) However, the `!important` didn't work out. I guess there is something sincerely wrong with the css!

Comment: @Michiel: I think the best thing you can do is removing that conditional comment and apply the rule to all browsers, then look in Firebug's or Chrome's web inspector and see which rules are applied (and try to get the rule containing `display: none` to be more important than other rules; usually this can be done by being more specific about the elements to which it is applied).